How do I disable shortcuts in WordPress?
I've restricted the blocks users have access to using add_filter( 'allowed_block_types' and it limits the choice of blocks users can add. This can however be bypassed with shortcuts. For example with the / command, it presents a list of blocks that shouldn't be available to users. Is there a way to completely disable shortcuts?
function restrict_blocks( $block_types, $post ) {
        $allowed = [
        'core/paragraph',
        'core/heading',
        'core/pullquote',
        'core/table',
        'core/audio',
        'core/image',
        'core/shortcode',
        'core/embed'
    ];
    
    if( is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
        return $allowed;
    }
    return $block_types;
}
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types', 'restrict_blocks', 10, 2);

I've also tried dequeuing the scripts however it doesn't deregister.
wp_dequeue_script( 'wp-keyboard-shortcuts' );
wp_deregister_script( 'wp-keyboard-shortcuts' );


If a block is registered in JavaScript you may also need to unregister it in JS: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#using-an-allow-list

@JacobPeattie, I tried but it doesn't seem to work function disable_autocomplete() {     echo '<script type="text/javascript">var allowedBlocks=["core/paragraph","core/heading","core/pullquote","core/table","core/audio","core/image","core/shortcode","core/embed"];wp.blocks.getBlockTypes().forEach(function(e){-1===allowedBlocks.indexOf(e.name)&&wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType(e.name)});</script>'; } add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_autocomplete' );
